# ASP.NET routing not working (only loading one route)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I setup my routing in Route.config, when I click on buttons on my master page which are supposed to go to different routes, it only goes to the first route in the route.config.

Route.config:

```
        // Profile/username/AccountInfo Route
        routes.MapPageRoute("ProfileAccountDetails",
        "Account/Profile/{username}/{accountDetails}",
        "~/Account/Profile/AccountDetails.aspx", true,
        new RouteValueDictionary { 
            { "username", "" },
            { "accountDetails", "" }});

        // Profile/username/Matches Route
        routes.MapPageRoute("ProfileMatches",
        "Account/Profile/{username}/{matches}",
        "~/Account/Profile/Matches.aspx", true,
        new RouteValueDictionary { 
            { "username", "" },
            { "matches", "" }});
```

Master page.aspx:

```
<div id="navProfile">
        <ul id="navBarProfile">
            <li class="navItemProfile"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="linkAccountInfo" CssClass="navLink" OnClick="AccountDetails_OnClick">Account Info</asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li class="navItemProfile"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="linkMatches" CssClass="navLink" OnClick="Matches_OnClick">My Matches</asp:LinkButton></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

MasterPage.cs:

```
    protected void AccountDetails_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteValueDictionary parameters = new RouteValueDictionary  
            { 
                {"username", currentUser.Username},
                {"accountDetails", "AccountDetails"}
            };
        VirtualPathData vpd = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, "ProfileAccountDetails", parameters);
        Response.Redirect(vpd.VirtualPath);
    }
    protected void Matches_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteValueDictionary parameters = new RouteValueDictionary  
            { 
                {"username", currentUser.Username},
                {"matches", "Matches"}
            };
        VirtualPathData vpd = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, "ProfileMatches", parameters);
        Response.Redirect(vpd.VirtualPath);
    }
```

It is only loading ACcountDetails.aspx and not Matches when I click on the Matches link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *Route.config* works very well. You added routes incorrectly. Your routes `"Account/Profile/{username}/{accountDetails}"` and `"Account/Profile/{username}/{matches}"` have the same format, that's why only one of two routes works. For example, `Account/Profile/TestUser/me` has the same format, as both routes. Change one of your routing maps (e.g. `Account/{username}/{matches}`)

Comment: @Bob if you get the answer, approve any answer and question will be solved. Otherwise other users also will answer it continuously.